# Modal View In TabBar iPhone App

Tags: iphone, view, modal-dialog, tabbar

I have TabBar app that loads several .xib files. In one of the views I am trying to load a modal view to compose an email in the app over the the view. I am using

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed {

     MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
     [controller setSubject:@"Email Subject"];
     [controller setMessageBody:@"Email Messgae" isHTML:NO];
     [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
     [controller release];
    }
```

I it has worked with several new view-based apps I built but not with the TabBar app. Whenever I try to run the action, nothing happens. Is there something I'm missing or am I going about it the wrong way?
Thanks!
If the answer is simple, sorry, I'm still learning!

EDIT: Additional info: rebuilt it and it now crashes when the action is run.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working? What happens when you step through the code? Is there an error? Does anything happen?

Comment: That's just it. I have the action linked to a button, and nothing happens when I press it.

Answer (score 1):

What is "self"? Is it the UITabBarController? If not, it should be. Or it could be a UINavigationController within the tab bar, which is probably better. Either way, it needs to be one of those to show a modal view.

You should also check whether it's linked up correctly in Interface Builder to set the selector on the button to call this function. I usually use TouchUpInside. Check to make sure whichever you are using is linked to your `buttonPressed` function.

Tell me if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

2 things

[1] NSLOG a message in the above and see if its actually linked (the log message should appear in the console)

[2] If it crashes, paste in a crash log

Hilton